# Optimizing very simple animations

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I'm creating a very simple animation. Here's one frame of it:

[image]

The only moving object in the sphere, but blender renders the whole view for each frame. Is it possible to optimize the rendering process of this animation?

Comment: There's an add-on that is capable of "animate" the render border. Here's its page on blendermarket: https://blendermarket.com/products/animated-render-border

Comment: This also looks like an adequate job for an OpenGL based viewport capture, rather than a fully ray traced rendering